# Minecraft Not Enough Items problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

So I got the NEI mod (Not Enough Items) and there's two things.
1. I can't get any items from cheat mode. I can turn on cheat mode, but I can't get any items from it.
2. I have about 7 other mods on minecraft, but NEI won't tell me how to craft the items. It tells me how to craft normal minecraft items, but not modded items. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What game mode are you in?

Comment: You must have cheats enabled in the world settings in order to cheat with NEI, but I don't know about the other problem. Some mods might not support NEI, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

you may need nei extention mods for the mods you have such as

> neiaddons https://bdew.net/neiaddons/

and

> nei intergration http://minecraft.curseforge.com/mc-mods/225251-nei-integration